# Are there any really interesting contemporary philosophers analyzing what a Wikipedia article should be like as compared to what it is like?

Tags: ontology, wikipedia

I have often considered that there could be a better explicit formula for how a Wikipedia page should be written but I have not yet formulated any such principles.

My main issue is that ideally a Wikipedia article would have some purely canonical way of presenting information about what some thing is, but it is not clear to me how that would work. To give one example, we can consider that the kinds of things written about a contemporary public figure would be very different from what would be written about the same person one thousand years from now from some very different culture. In some ways it makes me wonder if there could never be an actually “neutral” encyclopedia article, since the subject has to be reflected in some context to take on any kind of meaning. But I wouldn’t want to defeatistly accept that idea without struggling hard for the opposite, that there could be a way to present information canonically, based on some general template of what things are, what core properties define them, etc.

I asked Google Gemini Advanced (Gemini Ultra 1.0 I believe) this question and here is what it said:

> Absolutely! Here's a look at some contemporary philosophers and
> related disciplines focusing on Wikipedia's nature, exploring what it
> is and what it potentially could become:
>
> **Fields of Inquiry**
>
> - **Epistemology and the Philosophy of Knowledge:** Philosophers analyze how Wikipedia constructs and validates knowledge. Questions
>   arise:
>
>   - How does Wikipedia's collaborative model compare to traditional notions of expertise?
>   - What are the implications of Wikipedia's reliance on consensus for the concept of  "truth"?
>   - Can Wikipedia ever be considered a truly reliable source, given its open editing model?
> - **Philosophy of Technology and Information:** This field examines the technological and social underpinnings of Wikipedia. Think about:
>
>   - How Wikipedia's structure shapes the way information is presented and the types of knowledge that are privileged.
>   - The power dynamics within the Wikipedia community and how those affect article content and neutrality.
>   - Ethical issues surrounding free knowledge and the potential for misuse or manipulation within Wikipedia.
> - **Critical Theory and Social Philosophy:** These areas analyze Wikipedia through the lens of power, representation, and
>   marginalization. Consider:
>
>   - How Wikipedia reinforces dominant cultural narratives or perpetuates biases.
>   - The challenges of representing diverse viewpoints and marginalized voices within Wikipedia's consensus-driven model.
>   - Efforts to promote decolonization and inclusivity of knowledge construction on Wikipedia.
>
> **Notable Figures**
>
> While not all of these would self-identify as philosophers, they
> contribute substantial work to understanding Wikipedia's philosophical
> underpinnings:
>
> - **Phoebe Ayers:**  A librarian and researcher interested in the epistemology of Wikipedia, how reliability is determined, and the
>   intersection of libraries and this platform.
> - **Peter Suber:** A proponent of open access, Suber explores the philosophy of open knowledge and its implications for projects like
>   Wikipedia.
> - **Joseph M. Reagle Jr.:** Author of "Good Faith Collaboration: The Culture of Wikipedia," Reagle delves into the social dynamics and
>   culture of the Wikipedia community.
> - **Critical Art Ensemble:** This artist collective known for critical interventions, has explored the potential for disruption and creative
>   resistance within Wikipedia's structure.
>
> **Further Exploration**
>
> If you're looking for more information, here are some starting points:
>
> - **Wikipedia:WikiProject Philosophy:**  (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:WikiProject_Philosophy)
>   This project aims at improving philosophy-related content on
>   Wikipedia.
> - **Scholarly Journals:** Journals like *The Information Society* or *New Media & Society*  publish articles analyzing the philosophical aspects of Wikipedia.
> - **Conference Proceedings:** Conferences on digital humanities and internet culture often feature panels and papers discussing Wikipedia
>   from a critical perspective.
>
> **Let me know if you'd like a deeper dive into a particular aspect of philosophy and Wikipedia, or if you're interested in a specific
> thinker!**

Comment: I haven't been around philosophy.se for long - what is the policy here on questions asking people to detail with the output of Generative LLM engines?

Comment: *makes me wonder if there could never be an actually “neutral” encyclopedia article* is like asking *Please give me a view without a viewpoint*! I admit though that for articles with a political angle wikipedia is egregiously bad. Which therefore includes almost by definition most philosophy

Comment: @JonathanZ there is a large asymmetrical problem here: it takes seconds to generate a wall of text, but possibly _hours_ to validate its accuracy, let alone understand and comment meaningfully on it.

Comment: @mattdm - Yes, I agree. That's why, when this question said "I asked Google Gemini Advanced ... this question and here is what it said: ..." I thought that might be a reason for closure, but perhaps people here enjoy spending hours on possible hallucinations. So that's why I asked about the "official" policy, if there is one.